# BigQuery - concatenate ignoring NULL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null, concatenation

I'm very new to SQL. I understand in MySQL there's the CONCAT_WS function, but **BigQuery** doesn't recognise this.

I have a bunch of twenty fields I need to CONCAT into one comma-separated string, but some are NULL, and if one is NULL then the whole result will be NULL. Here's what I have so far:

```
CONCAT(m.track1, ", ", m.track2))) As Tracks,
```

I tried this but it returns NULL too:

```
CONCAT(m.track1, IFNULL(m.track2,CONCAT(", ", m.track2))) As Tracks,
```

Super grateful for any advice, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, BigQuery doesn't support `concat_ws()`.  So, one method is `string_agg()`:

```
select t.*,
       (select string_agg(track, ',')
        from (select t.track1 as track union all select t.track2) x
       ) x
from t;
```

Actually a simpler method uses arrays:

```
select t.*,
       array_to_string([track1, track2], ',')
```

Arrays with `NULL` values are not supported in result sets, but they can be used for intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gordon. I don't quite follow the string_agg() method but I will work on it. The array method is really elegant.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a bunch of twenty fields I need to CONCAT into one comma-separated string

Assuming that these are the only fields in the table - you can use below approach - generic enough to handle any number of columns and their names w/o explicit enumeration

```
select  
  (select string_agg(col, ', ' order by offset)
  from unnest(split(trim(format('%t', (select as struct t.*)), '()'), ', ')) col with offset
  where not upper(col) = 'NULL'
  ) as Tracks
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

Below is oversimplified dummy example to try, test the approach

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 track1, 2 track2, 3 track3, 4 track4 union all
  select 5, null, 7, 8
)
select  
  (select string_agg(col, ', ' order by offset)
  from unnest(split(trim(format('%t', (select as struct t.*)), '()'), ', ')) col with offset
  where not upper(col) = 'NULL'
  ) as Tracks
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

[image]